# Query not returning rows on user input MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-reports

I am running below query in access in which i need to take argument from end user. Following query is used. However, when i don't ask for user input & put the condition in the query like this (`tblApplications.txtApplicant Like "*dac*"`)  it returns values and as soon as i asked for user input it returns blank.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT
    tblConstruction.txtConstructionNr AS [Constr-Nr] AS Amount,
    tblApplications.txtFolder
FROM
    tblApplications
    LEFT JOIN tblConstruction
        ON tblApplications.IDConstAppli = tblConstruction.IDConstr
WHERE
    (((tblApplications.txtApplicant) Like "*" & [Please enter the applicant or parts thereof:] & "*") AND
    ((tblApplications.txtDecission) Like "open"))
ORDER BY
    tblApplications.txtApplicant,
    tblApplications.[txtKomm-Nr],
    tblApplications.txtDecissionDat DESC;
```

Comment: how do you run your query?

Comment: with "run" option @4dmonster

Comment: Have you selected "SQL Server Compatible Syntax" in Access options?  If so use `%` instead of `*` as the `Like` wildcard.

Comment: But `tblAntraege` is not included in your query, so how should it possibly work?

Comment: @Gustav query was edited by another user & he forget to update in the body.

Comment: @HansUp i am new to Access. I dont know where to set this option. Also i would like to tell you Tables are linked to Mysql. Just to update i change to "%" and again it works fine when i give condition in query but as soon as i changed to user input. It stops working

Comment: Looking closer, I suspect it may not matter.  You question shows `tblApplications.txtApplicant Like "dac"` works.  But when I look at the raw text, it seems you may have meant to tell us that `tblApplications.txtApplicant Like "*dac*"` works.  If that is the case, it's not the wildcard problem I suspected.  And you should fix the question so it displays correctly.

Comment: @HansUp yes it works `tblApplications.txtApplicant Like "*dac*"` but its not working for the input

Answer (score 0):

If your table is linked to MySQL, use the MySQL wildcards:

> %   matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> _    matches exactly one character.

Instead of `*` and `?` as for Access.

```
...
tblApplications.txtApplicant Like "%" & [Please enter the applicant or parts thereof:] & "%"
...
```

The collation of the column might be case sensitive. Try entering the search term in the right case.

Comment: As mentioned earlier changing to `%` is not working. And I gave the term in right case even then its not returning any row